# how to convert code older version of tensorflow into tensorflow 2.0

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

how can i convert my older version of tensorflow code to newer version as CNN ,RNN ,CTC is not working in newer version. I updated tensorflow thereafter many of the function stop working properly and shows error. Some of the function are not in the package anymore.
 I dont have idea about how to convert it into new version of the tensorflow

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function, unicode_literals
import codecs
import sys
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

from DataLoader import FilePaths

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

 class DecoderType:
BestPath = 0
WordBeamSearch = 1
BeamSearch = 2


class Model:
# Model Constants
batchSize = 10 # 50
imgSize = (800, 64)
maxTextLen = 100

def __init__(self, charList, decoderType=DecoderType.BestPath, mustRestore=False):
    self.charList = charList
    self.decoderType = decoderType
    self.mustRestore = mustRestore
    self.snapID = 0


    # input image batch
    self.inputImgs =tf.compat.v1.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, Model.imgSize[0], Model.imgSize[1]))





    # setup CNN, RNN and CTC

    self.setupCNN()
    self.setupRNN()
    self.setupCTC()
    # setup optimizer to train NN

    self.batchesTrained = 0

    self.learningRate = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[])
    self.optimizer = tf.train.RMSPropOptimizer(self.learningRate).minimize(self.loss)

    # Initialize TensorFlow
    (self.sess, self.saver) = self.setupTF()

    self.training_loss_summary = tf.summary.scalar('loss', self.loss)
    self.writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(
       './logs', self.sess.graph)  # Tensorboard: Create writer
    self.merge = tf.summary.merge([self.training_loss_summary])  # Tensorboard: Merge

def setupCNN(self):

    """ Create CNN layers and return output of these layers """

    cnnIn4d = tf.expand_dims(input=self.inputImgs, axis=3)

    # First Layer: Conv (5x5) + Pool (2x2) - Output size: 400 x 32 x 64
    with tf.name_scope('Conv_Pool_1'):
        kernel = tf.Variable(
            tf.random.truncated_normal([5, 5, 1, 64], stddev=0.1))
        conv = tf.nn.conv2d(
            cnnIn4d, kernel, padding='SAME', strides=(1, 1, 1, 1))
        learelu = tf.nn.leaky_relu(conv, alpha=0.01)
        pool = tf.nn.max_pool2d(learelu, (1, 2, 2, 1), (1, 2, 2, 1), 'VALID')

    # Second Layer: Conv (5x5) + Pool (1x2) - Output size: 400 x 16 x 128
    with tf.name_scope('Conv_Pool_2'):
        kernel = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(
            [5, 5, 64, 128], stddev=0.1))
        conv = tf.nn.conv2d(
            pool, kernel, padding='SAME', strides=(1, 1, 1, 1))
        learelu = tf.nn.leaky_relu(conv, alpha=0.01)
        pool = tf.nn.max_pool(learelu, (1, 1, 2, 1), (1, 1, 2, 1), 'VALID')

    # Third Layer: Conv (3x3) + Pool (2x2) + Simple Batch Norm - Output size: 200 x 8 x 128
    with tf.name_scope('Conv_Pool_BN_3'):
        kernel = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(
            [3, 3, 128, 128], stddev=0.1))
        conv = tf.nn.conv2d(
            pool, kernel, padding='SAME', strides=(1, 1, 1, 1))
        mean, variance = tf.nn.moments(conv, axes=[0])
        batch_norm = tf.nn.batch_normalization(
            conv, mean, variance, offset=None, scale=None, variance_epsilon=0.001)
        learelu = tf.nn.leaky_relu(batch_norm, alpha=0.01)
        pool = tf.nn.max_pool(learelu, (1, 2, 2, 1), (1, 2, 2, 1), 'VALID')

    # Fourth Layer: Conv (3x3) - Output size: 200 x 8 x 256
    with tf.name_scope('Conv_4'):
        kernel = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(
            [3, 3, 128, 256], stddev=0.1))
        conv = tf.nn.conv2d(
            pool, kernel, padding='SAME', strides=(1, 1, 1, 1))
        learelu = tf.nn.leaky_relu(conv, alpha=0.01)

    # Fifth Layer: Conv (3x3) + Pool(2x2) - Output size: 100 x 4 x 256
    with tf.name_scope('Conv_Pool_5'):
        kernel = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(
            [3, 3, 256, 256], stddev=0.1))
        conv = tf.nn.conv2d(
            learelu, kernel, padding='SAME', strides=(1, 1, 1, 1))
        learelu = tf.nn.leaky_relu(conv, alpha=0.01)
        pool = tf.nn.max_pool(learelu, (1, 2, 2, 1), (1, 2, 2, 1), 'VALID')

    # Sixth Layer: Conv (3x3) + Pool(1x2) + Simple Batch Norm - Output size: 100 x 2 x 512
    with tf.name_scope('Conv_Pool_BN_6'):
        kernel = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(
            [3, 3, 256, 512], stddev=0.1))
        conv = tf.nn.conv2d(
            pool, kernel, padding='SAME', strides=(1, 1, 1, 1))
        mean, variance = tf.nn.moments(conv, axes=[0])
        batch_norm = tf.nn.batch_normalization(
            conv, mean, variance, offset=None, scale=None, variance_epsilon=0.001)
        learelu = tf.nn.leaky_relu(batch_norm, alpha=0.01)
        pool = tf.nn.max_pool(learelu, (1, 1, 2, 1), (1, 1, 2, 1), 'VALID')


    # Seventh Layer: Conv (3x3) + Pool (1x2) - Output size: 100 x 1 x 512
    with tf.name_scope('Conv_Pool_7'):
        kernel = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(
            [3, 3, 512, 512], stddev=0.1))
        conv = tf.nn.conv2d(
            pool, kernel, padding='SAME', strides=(1, 1, 1, 1))
        learelu = tf.nn.leaky_relu(conv, alpha=0.01)
        pool = tf.nn.max_pool(learelu, (1, 1, 2, 1), (1, 1, 2, 1), 'VALID')

        self.cnnOut4d = pool

def setupRNN(self):
    """ Create RNN layers and return output of these layers """
    # Collapse layer to remove dimension 100 x 1 x 512 --> 100 x 512 on axis=2
    rnnIn3d = tf.squeeze(self.cnnOut4d, axis=[2])

    # 2 layers of LSTM cell used to build RNN
    numHidden = 512
    cells = [tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMCell(
        num_units=numHidden, state_is_tuple=True, name='basic_lstm_cell') for _ in range(2)]
    stacked = tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell(cells, state_is_tuple=True)
    # Bi-directional RNN
    # BxTxF -> BxTx2H
    ((forward, backward), _) = tf.nn.bidirectional_dynamic_rnn(
        cell_fw=stacked, cell_bw=stacked, inputs=rnnIn3d, dtype=rnnIn3d.dtype)

    # BxTxH + BxTxH -> BxTx2H -> BxTx1X2H
    concat = tf.expand_dims(tf.concat([forward, backward], 2), 2)

    # Project output to chars (including blank): BxTx1x2H -> BxTx1xC -> BxTxC
    kernel = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(
        [1, 1, numHidden * 2, len(self.charList) + 1], stddev=0.1))
    self.rnnOut3d = tf.squeeze(tf.nn.atrous_conv2d(value=concat, filters=kernel, rate=1, padding='SAME'), axis=[2])

def setupCTC(self):
    """ Create CTC loss and decoder and return them """
    # BxTxC -> TxBxC
    self.ctcIn3dTBC = tf.transpose(self.rnnOut3d, [1, 0, 2])

    # Ground truth text as sparse tensor
    with tf.name_scope('CTC_Loss'):
        self.gtTexts = tf.SparseTensor(tf.placeholder(tf.int64, shape=[
                                       None, 2]), tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None]), tf.placeholder(tf.int64, [2]))
        # Calculate loss for batch
        self.seqLen = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None])
        self.loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.ctc_loss(labels=self.gtTexts, inputs=self.ctcIn3dTBC, sequence_length=self.seqLen,
                           ctc_merge_repeated=True, ignore_longer_outputs_than_inputs=True))
    with tf.name_scope('CTC_Decoder'):
        # Decoder: Best path decoding or Word beam search decoding
        if self.decoderType == DecoderType.BestPath:
            self.decoder = tf.nn.ctc_greedy_decoder(
                inputs=self.ctcIn3dTBC, sequence_length=self.seqLen)
        elif self.decoderType == DecoderType.BeamSearch:
            self.decoder = tf.nn.ctc_beam_search_decoder(inputs=self.ctcIn3dTBC, sequence_length=self.seqLen, beam_width=50, merge_repeated=True)
        elif self.decoderType == DecoderType.WordBeamSearch:
            # Import compiled word beam search operation (see https://github.com/githubharald/CTCWordBeamSearch)
            word_beam_search_module = tf.load_op_library(
                './TFWordBeamSearch.so')

            # Prepare: dictionary, characters in dataset, characters forming words
            chars = codecs.open(FilePaths.wordCharList.txt, 'r').read()
            wordChars = codecs.open(
                FilePaths.fnWordCharList, 'r').read()
            corpus = codecs.open(FilePaths.corpus.txt, 'r').read()

            # # Decoder using the "NGramsForecastAndSample": restrict number of (possible) next words to at most 20 words: O(W) mode of word beam search
            # decoder = word_beam_search_module.word_beam_search(tf.nn.softmax(ctcIn3dTBC, dim=2), 25, 'NGramsForecastAndSample', 0.0, corpus.encode('utf8'), chars.encode('utf8'), wordChars.encode('utf8'))

            # Decoder using the "Words": only use dictionary, no scoring: O(1) mode of word beam search
            self.decoder = word_beam_search_module.word_beam_search(tf.nn.softmax(
                self.ctcIn3dTBC, dim=2), 25, 'Words', 0.0, corpus.encode('utf8'), chars.encode('utf8'), wordChars.encode('utf8'))

    # Return a CTC operation to compute the loss and CTC operation to decode the RNN output
    return self.loss, self.decoder

def setupTF(self):
    """ Initialize TensorFlow """
    print('Python: ' + sys.version)
    print('Tensorflow: ' + tf.__version__)
    sess = tf.Session()  # Tensorflow session
    saver = tf.train.Saver(max_to_keep=3)  # Saver saves model to file
    modelDir = '../model/'
    latestSnapshot = tf.train.latest_checkpoint(modelDir)  # Is there a saved model?
    # If model must be restored (for inference), there must be a snapshot
    if self.mustRestore and not latestSnapshot:
        raise Exception('No saved model found in: ' + modelDir)
    # Load saved model if available
    if latestSnapshot:
        print('Init with stored values from ' + latestSnapshot)
        saver.restore(sess, latestSnapshot)
    else:
        print('Init with new values')
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

    return (sess, saver)

def toSpare(self, texts):
    """ Convert ground truth texts into sparse tensor for ctc_loss """
    indices = []
    values = []
    shape = [len(texts), 0]  # Last entry must be max(labelList[i])
    # Go over all texts
    for (batchElement, texts) in enumerate(texts):
        # Convert to string of label (i.e. class-ids)
        # print(texts)
        # labelStr = []
        # for c in texts:
        #     print(c, '|', end='')
        #     labelStr.append(self.charList.index(c))
        # print(' ')
        labelStr = [self.charList.index(c) for c in texts]
        # Sparse tensor must have size of max. label-string
        if len(labelStr) > shape[1]:
            shape[1] = len(labelStr)
        # Put each label into sparse tensor
        for (i, label) in enumerate(labelStr):
            indices.append([batchElement, i])
            values.append(label)

    return (indices, values, shape)

def decoderOutputToText(self, ctcOutput):
    """ Extract texts from output of CTC decoder """
    # Contains string of labels for each batch element
    encodedLabelStrs = [[] for i in range(Model.batchSize)]
    # Word beam search: label strings terminated by blank
    if self.decoderType == DecoderType.WordBeamSearch:
        blank = len(self.charList)
        for b in range(Model.batchSize):
            for label in ctcOutput[b]:
                if label == blank:
                    break
                encodedLabelStrs[b].append(label)
    # TF decoders: label strings are contained in sparse tensor
    else:
        # Ctc returns tuple, first element is SparseTensor
        decoded = ctcOutput[0][0]
        # Go over all indices and save mapping: batch -> values
        idxDict = {b : [] for b in range(Model.batchSize)}
        for (idx, idx2d) in enumerate(decoded.indices):
            label = decoded.values[idx]
            batchElement = idx2d[0]  # index according to [b,t]
            encodedLabelStrs[batchElement].append(label)
    # Map labels to chars for all batch elements
    return [str().join([self.charList[c] for c in labelStr]) for labelStr in encodedLabelStrs]

def trainBatch(self, batch, batchNum):
    """ Feed a batch into the NN to train it """
    sparse = self.toSpare(batch.gtTexts)
    rate = 0.01 if self.batchesTrained < 10 else (
        0.001 if self.batchesTrained < 2750 else 0.001)
    evalList = [self.merge, self.optimizer, self.loss]
    feedDict = {self.inputImgs( batch.imgs), self.gtTexts( sparse), self.seqLen ([Model.maxTextLen] * Model.batchSize), self.learningRate( rate)}
    (loss_summary, _, lossVal) = self.sess.run(evalList, feedDict)
    # Tensorboard: Add loss_summary to writer
    self.writer.add_summary(loss_summary, batchNum)
    self.batchesTrained += 1
    return lossVal

def return_rnn_out(self, batch, write_on_csv=False):
    """Only return rnn_out prediction value without decoded"""
    numBatchElements = len(batch.imgs)
    decoded, rnnOutput = self.sess.run([self.decoder, self.ctcIn3dTBC],
                            {self.inputImgs: batch.imgs, self.seqLen: [Model.maxTextLen] * numBatchElements})

    decoded = rnnOutput
    print(decoded.shape)

    if write_on_csv:
        s = rnnOutput.shape
        b = 0
        csv = ''
        for t in range(s[0]):
            for c in range(s[2]):
                csv += str(rnnOutput[t, b, c]) + ';'
            csv += '\n'
        open('mat_0.csv', 'w').write(csv)

    return decoded[:,0,:].reshape(100,80)

def inferBatch(self, batch):
    """ Feed a batch into the NN to recognize texts """
    numBatchElements = len(batch.imgs)
    feedDict = {self.inputImgs: batch.imgs, self.seqLen: [Model.maxTextLen] * numBatchElements}
    evalRes = self.sess.run([self.decoder, self.ctcIn3dTBC], feedDict)
    decoded = evalRes[0]
    # # Dump RNN output to .csv file
    # decoded, rnnOutput = self.sess.run([self.decoder, self.rnnOutput], {
    #                                    self.inputImgs: batch.imgs, self.seqLen: [Model.maxTextLen] * Model.batchSize})
    # s = rnnOutput.shape
    # b = 0
    # csv = ''
    # for t in range(s[0]):
    #     for c in range(s[2]):
    #         csv += str(rnnOutput[t, b, c]) + ';'
    #     csv += '\n'
    # open('mat_0.csv', 'w').write(csv)

    texts = self.decoderOutputToText(decoded)
    return texts

def save(self):
    """ Save model to file """
    self.snapID += 1
    self.saver.save(self.sess, r'C:\Users\PycharmProjects\hand\model\snapshot',
                    global_step=self.snapID)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run tf1 code in tf2 by importing tf a bit differently:

```
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
tf.disable_v2_behavior()
```

For details on how to migrate your code you should look here: https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/migrate